# jquery removeAttr not working

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, attr

Hello i'm trying to use autocomplete dropdownlist plugin that name is ufd.
Anyway, I have dropdownlist and i want to get this selected value (or text) on codebehind click_event.
if i can remove all selected attr from dropdownlist and add selected attr to selected option, this will work.But this removeAttr doesn't work:( Please help me.

```
       $(function () {
        var element = $("#DropDownList1");
        $(element).change(function () {
        $(element).find('option').removeAttr('selected'); //this is not working
        $(element + "option[value=" + $(element).val() + "]").attr("selected", "selected");
        });
       });

    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

codebehind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (TalepService tService = new TalepService())
        {
            DropDownList1.DataSource = tService.ddlTalepDurumDoldur();
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "talepDurumu";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "talepDurumID";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        string value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you doing this at all? It looks like when a `change` occurs, you're manually doing what the browser does automatically. I mean if a `change` event occurs, then the selected option will have already been changed.

Comment: i answered jasper what i'm trying. i dunno why but when i select any option (change), can't see this is selected on firebug. thats why i wanna do it manually to get this value on codebehind. problem is continuing:)

Comment: What do you mean you can't see it is selected on firebug? If you want the value, just do `$(this).val()`, but there shouldn't be any reason to manipulate attributes.

Comment: okay okay i did it but i dunno why this works:) i just replaced datasource like this:  foreach (var item in tService.ddlTalepDurumDoldur())
                    DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(item.talepDurumu, item.talepDurumID.ToString()));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating jQuery objects from jQuery objects, which is having an issue on this line (I'm assuming):

```
$(element + "option[value=" + $(element).val() + "]").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Because `element` is a jQuery object (keyword, object) and you are adding a string to that object.

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    var element = $("#DropDownList1");
    element.change(function () {
        var theVal = element.val();//get the current value since it will be removed on the next line
        element.find('option').removeAttr('selected'); //this is not working
        element.find("option[value=" + theVal + "]").attr("selected", "selected");
    });
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LjhwW/1/

While creating this demo I realized the same thing as "am not i am" (in the comments). Why are you manually changing the selected option element for the `change` event, the browser will do this anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`element` is already a jQuery object so you don't have to use `$()` on it. Generally we prefix `$` to variable name if it is a jQuery object. Try this.

```
$(function () {
    var $element = $("#DropDownList1");
    $element.change(function () {
       var val = this.value;
       $element.find('option').removeAttr('selected')
       .filter("[value=" + val + "]")
       .attr("selected", "selected");
    });
});
```

Comment: I posted pretty much the same code and realized that getting `$element.val()` on the last line of the `change` event handler won't return anything because the line before it is removing the `selected` attribute. Also you have a semi-colon after the first line in the `change` event handler that will stop execution.

Comment: @Jasper - Thanks for the semicolon, missed it totally.

Comment: Hehe, I tried the same work around with `this.value`, the fix is to cache the value of the select before wiping it: http://jsfiddle.net/LjhwW/2/ (this is a demo of your code)

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to change the selected value of a select with jquery is by setting its value.

```
$("#DropDownList1").val("new-selected-value")
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `selectedIndex` property of the `SELECT` to -1 to clear the selected item.